# How can I modify following ps command to print in comma separated value (CSV) format?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, ps

I have following command:

```
ps -e -o pcpu,pmem,args,pid --sort=pcpu | sed '5q' | awk ' {print $1,$2,$3,$4 }'
```

Its output is:

```
%CPU %MEM COMMAND PID
0.0 0.1 /sbin/init 1
0.0 0.0 [kthreadd] 2
0.0 0.0 [ksoftirqd/0] 3
0.0 0.0 [kworker/0:0H] 5
```

how can I modify my original command given above to print out in csv format like as shown below:

```
   %CPU, %MEM, COMMAND, PID
    0.0, 0.1, /sbin/init, 1
    0.0, 0.0, [kthreadd], 2
    0.0, 0.0, [ksoftirqd/0], 3
    0.0, 0.0, [kworker/0:0H], 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa an Output Field Separator (OFS). Add `OFS=", ";` to your awk command:

```
ps -e -o pcpu,pmem,args,pid --sort=pcpu | sed '5q' | awk ' {OFS=", "; print $1,$2,$3,$4 }'
```

or shorter:

```
ps -e -o pcpu,pmem,args,pid --sort=pcpu | awk 'NR<=5 {OFS=", "; print $1,$2,$3,$4 }'
```

Output (example):

```
%CPU, %MEM, COMMAND, PID
0.0, 0.0, [migration/0], 6
0.0, 0.0, [migration/1], 7
0.0, 0.0, [migration/2], 11
0.0, 0.0, [migration/3], 14
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web)